# Regarding isolating reaources created by two users in subscription in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-group

I have one AD associated with one subscription and  I need to create two users and need to isolate the resources created by them. Is this really possible? since I am new to Azure I am not much aware of this. It would be great if someone render their hand.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to create two users and need to isolate the resources created by them. Is this really possible?

Yes.  To isolate them from a management and administration point-of-view, create two [resource groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/overview#resource-groups), and add each user to the appropriate [role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles) on one resource group.